# Downgrade from Windows 10 to 8.1 without Windows.old folder

Tags: windows-10, windows-8.1, downgrade

I accidentally deleted the `Windows.old` folder from the Recycle Bin. Now I want to downgrade from Windows 10 to Windows 8.1. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

There are three ways to downgrade:

1. The "uninstall" method. This relies on the Windows.old directory and is only valid so long as that folder exists.
2. The third-party backup method. This assumes you have created a backup using a third party backup tool prior to upgrading.
3. The clean install method. If you do not have the choice of the first two options, the remaining option is to use Windows 8 installation media and run a Clean Installation. This does not keep any data on the OS drive and you will need to know your license key.

Answer (score 1):

Windows.Old contains files of your System drive ( Usually C) before format, the entries under your start menu, registry settings, users and more. Its size of Windows.Old after upgrade is noticeable, and for recent updates in Windows 10 there is a time period after which it is deleted automatically.

Sadly "RESTORE" to Windows 8.1 would not be possible as you have already deleted your backups of previous system partition .

But a clean install can take you back to Windows 8.1, always keep your personal data safe first before trying these upgrades or downgrades on a separate partition.

Comment: No affect , except that you might or even might not loose your data depending on your existing partitions and how you store files.
Either you have all the disk as one partition, or you could have configured to have windows in one partition and reset data i other, so if seperate partition your data is still safe, if all in one partition it will be formated.

Answer (score -1):

If your PC came with Windows 8.1 on it (before upgrading to Windows 10) and there is a factory restore partition on your hard disk, you could just run the PC's factory restore procedure and the PC will be reverted to the original state.  How to do this depends on the brand of the PC.

Comment: Why the downvote with no explanation?  It would be understandable if there is no factory recovery partition on the HDD, but this solution will work when applicable.

Answer (score -1):

If you are willing to downgrade at any risk, that is no data saving required . Here are the steps along with any further steps needed.
1- On your current system download the 2 files below
   [Windows 8.1 ISO from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/software-download/windows8ISO)

and 
[Rufus To make a Bootable pen-drive/ USB](https://rufus.ie/en_IE.html)

2 - Make a bootable USB from Rufus by selecting your USB Device and ISO you downloaded, partitioning scheme - GPT preferred ( unless you are now on MBR System )

and along with GPT Select UEFI

Click start to make it bootable.

3 - Restart your System and at power on press the button to choose your USB as boot device, keep note that if you selected GOT in above step select the Option with EFI/UEFI with you USB Bootable Device name.

4- Install Windows 8.1 with following steps
    Select your Language(country) and Click Next and Install Now
    Accept any License agreement .
If it asks for any product key you can use one if you have or safely skip, windows will activate it self later if you had OEM Windows keys. Or for the time you can also you some [generic windows keys](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/kmsclientkeys)
     Select Custom Install and partition your disk as you require
 NOTE: if you have MBR disk and you boot in UEFI mode you have error.

Click install now on the partition you want.

Setup completes in some time.
5 - Install the drivers.